# Akka Stream serialization exception and die

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I´m using Kakfa-client with Akka stream, and even having a Supervisor Strategy defined in my materializer

```
    materializer = ActorMaterializer(createActorMaterializerSettings(strategyDecider, inputBuffer, system))
  private def createActorMaterializerSettings(strategyDecider: function.Function[Throwable, Supervision.Directive], inputBuffer: Int, system: ActorSystem) = {
    ActorMaterializerSettings(system)
      .withDispatcher("akka.stream-sink-dispatcher")
      .withSupervisionStrategy(toScalaFunction(strategyDecider))
      .withInputBuffer(initialSize = 1, maxSize = inputBuffer)
  }
```

When I receive something that I cannot deserialize

```
akka stream die org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition
```

My stream dont use the supervisor strategry and die.

Any idea what to do here?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with Kafka client, not Akka. What are you using JSON, Avro? Do you have any more debug on what caused the serialization problem ie. what specifically in the message could not be deserialized when consumed off of the topic?

Comment: The problem is because we configure the client to deserialize strings, but arrive an Integer

Comment: So are you saying that a particular field in your message schema is sometimes a string and sometimes an integer? Are you in control of the system that produces the messages?

Comment: I cannot control what people add into the topic

Comment: can you add a `filter` stage that checks whether the message is valid?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this deserialization  is something that is happening inside the Kafka consumer actor, that the library create internally. I believe is unresolved bug in Kafka Akka stream  client

Comment: Can you control the deserialization itself? You could create a deserializer returning `Either[Junk, YourType]`, which you would use to return Left instread of throwing. Then you would just collect Right.

Comment: The Kafka consumer actor deserialize as you tell him. So I could tell him to deserialize in raw byte array and then deserialize again in the specific one in a map in my stream, but that would means two deserilization which obviously it would affect the performance of my connector. Here the question is why the Kafka consumer actor is not working with the strategy decider when is in the documentation?. Is just a bug that at some point need to be tackle